# Space/offset series plotted on same graph with categorical x values in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm hoping someone can help me adjust a plot in R. [csv file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hh8yb4tem6ewqif/occupancy.csv) I have plotted mean values with error bars of three series (Ctr, Fat, Imp). However, I would like to offset them so they are not all stacked on top of one another.

The data look like:

```
Spp occ   L.95CRI   U.95CRI bait
A   0.633   0.374   0.868   Fat
A   0.915   0.682   1       Imp
A   0.779   0.581   0.94    Ctr
B   0.51    0.102   0.866   Fat
B   0.767   0.235   1       Imp
B   0.676   0.279   0.98    Ctr
```

where "Spp" is the categorical x-axis label and "occ" is the value I want to plot with error bars for each series "bait". Lower error values are "L.95CRI" and upper errors are "U.95CRI".

The code I'm using is:

```
data<-read.csv("occupancy.csv")
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Spp, occ, data=data, colour=bait, geom=c("line","point")) 
   + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=L.95CRI, ymax=U.95CRI))
```

My current graph looks like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3m09406knqay3ot/graph.png)

I would like the green "Fat" series to be shifted over so that it plots just to the right of the red "Ctr" series, and the blue "Imp" series shifted over so that it plots just to the right of the green "Fat" series. This way all 3 series for "A" can be viewed side-by-side instead of overlayed on top of one another, then all 3 series for "B", and so forth. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `dodge` ('offset') the `position` of the points and error bars. E.g. something like:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Spp, y = occ,
                      ymin = L.95CRI, ymax = U.95CRI,
                      colour = bait)) +
  geom_point(position = dodge) +
  geom_errorbar(position = dodge, width = 0.1)
```

[image]

You find [**more examples here**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/#line-graphs)

Answer (score 0):

Try  [`geom_pointrange`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_pointrange.html).

Also, maybe check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510003/can-one-offset-jitter-points-in-ggplot-boxplot) for something similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I did find that but have been struggling to make it fit my situation. I'll try geom_pointrange too. Much appreciated.